# Sorting arrays in Python by a non-integer column

Tags: python, sorting

So for example I have an array that I want to sort by a column in an ascending order, and it's easy to do for integers using 'sorting()', 'np.arrange()', or 'np.argsort()'.

However, what if my column is consisting of floats?

### What would you recommend?

Edit:
I mean, I have something like:

```
a = array([[1.7, 2, 3],
           [4.5, 5, 6],
           [0.1, 0, 1]])
```

and I want to get this:

```
array([[0.1, 0, 1],
       [1.7, 2, 3],
       [4.5, 5, 6]])
```

So far with `argsort()` I get the following error:
`Type Error: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: You can sort with floats just like with integers.

Comment: I dont see any Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard Python's [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) (or `sort` for in-place sorting), no matter what is contained in the sequence. Just use a custom `key`, or a custom compare function (`cmp`). For example, to sort a list of lists (2-d array) ascending by 4th column:

```
>>> a=[[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], [4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0], [0,0,0,0]]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(3))
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this in `numpy` is to specify the correct `axis` you want to sort on, by default it sorts on `axis=-1`:

```
>>> np.sort(a, axis=0)
array([[ 0.1,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.7,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 4.5,  5. ,  6. ]])
```

Or inplace:

```
>>> a.sort(axis=0)
>>> a
array([[ 0.1,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.7,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 4.5,  5. ,  6. ]])
```

To sort *just* on a specific column you can use `argsort()`, e.g. column `0`:

```
>>> a[np.argsort(a[:,0])]
array([[ 0.1,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.7,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 4.5,  5. ,  6. ]])
```

Comment: I believe this is not what the OP wants. This will sort numbers *along the axis, but in isolation*, it will not sort rows according to value in the n-th column.

Comment: The OP's example doesn't make that clear, sorting integers and floats works the same. Updated to include sorting based on a single `float` column.